# TypeScript: Class generics - something like Java's Class<T extends Foo>

Tags: class, generics, typescript, reflection

I have a TypeScript code that processes classes (OGM framework).

There is a base class for models/entities, say, `BaseModel`.
However, I would like to support several different base model classes, e.g. `ProxiedBaseModel` and `DecoratedBaseModel`.

The issue is:

```
export abstract class DiscriminatorMapping<BaseModelT>
{
    public static getMapping() : 
        { [key: string]: typeof BaseModelT } 
    { ... }
```

This is a simple dictionary-like class.
It needs a map of  `string` <-> class.
And `typeof BaseModelT` obviously doesn't work as TypeScript can't know what type will come in.

**How should I express that the class type parameter takes something that is a class?**
I already know how to represent the type of any class, that's `{ new (): <any> }`. But I don't know how to apply it here:

```
class DiscriminatorMapping<BaseModelT extends { new (): <any> }>
```

Maybe I should introduce some type alias?

*Update:* I have tried

```
export abstract class DiscriminatorMapping<BaseModelClassT>
{
    public static getMapping() : { [key: string]: BaseModelClassT } { return {}; }
```

(Using `BaseModelClassT` to express it's a class type ("`Class<T>`"), not a model type itself.)
But this is invalid:

> Static members cannot reference class type parameters.

I need it static because of the mechanism how the generated data get into the static field through subclasses' static field of the same name.

So currently I solve it by having the same 2 classes, differing only in imports:

```
import {BaseFrameModel as BaseModel} from './BaseFrameModel';
// vs.
import {BaseModel} from './BaseModel';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your updated code declares a mapping from `string` to instance of `BaseModelClass` which isn't want you want.

Since there's no access to the generic constraints from static members, you'll need to make the static method generic itself:

```
export abstract class DiscriminatorMapping<BaseModelT> {
    public static getMapping<BaseModelT2>(): { [key: string]: { new(): BaseModelT2 } } {
      return null;
    }
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20abstract%20class%20DiscriminatorMapping%3CBaseModelT%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20public%20static%20getMapping%3CBaseModelT%3E()%3A%20%7B%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20%7B%20new()%3A%20BaseModelT%20%7D%20%7D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20null%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D))

You can name `BaseModelT2` just the same (without the 2), but I added it to make it stand out.

Comment: `BaseModelClass` is not a class, it's just a type. I would use it like `DisMap<typeof TBaseModel>` Better name would be `TBaseModel`.  Changed in Q. Anyway, going to try, thanks!

Comment: Maybe the proper way to do would be to find other mechanism to bring the generated data to `DiscriminatorMapping`. I wanted a singleton but there was an issue with Angular2 / SystemJS loading...

Comment: Obviously `BaseModelClass` is a type, but it represents a class that instances of it are the values of this map. I'm pretty sure that the code I posted answers what you're looking for

Comment: No no, the values of the map are the classes. I am mapping strings to types. In Java, it would be `Map<String, Class<T>>`. But since TS doesn't have `Class` class equivalent, I need to use a generic type for it and feed it with `typeof ProxiedBaseModel` somewhere.

Comment: I know that they are classes! But the way you wrote it it's like in java to do: `Map<String, T>`, that's my point. The code I posed is what you're looking for. Have you tried it?